# How was it known that the monolith sent its signal to Jupiter in 2001?

Tags: movie, 2001-a-space-odyssey

(Warning: spoilers ahead /s)

When the monolith is uncovered on the moon in 2001: A Space Odyssey, it generates a massive, but brief radio signal when it is illuminated by the Sun for the first time.

Given that:

- The signal lasted no more than 30 seconds
- The time and date of the exposure to the Sun was effectively random
- No one expected the monolith to generate any sort of signal

How did anyone know that this signal was directed towards Jupiter (in the movie), or Saturn (in the book)?

Comment: I just assumed the signal from the Lunar monolith caused the Jupiter one to signal - and when that one was detected they realized the Lunar one had contacted it and said aimed at Jupiter as shorthand.

Comment: How a monolith can generate a narrow signal and aim it is a mystery.  It might be linked with the other monoliths.  But a monolith is basically a super computer / quantum computer so calculating where Jupiter (or Saturn) is should not be difficult.  My understanding is the light show / life in a room at the end isn't a Cosmos style wormhole - it is Dave getting entangled into the supercomputer.

Comment: @lucasbachmann In the movie, they didn't even know that the Jupiter monolith existed until Bowman saw it first hand.

Comment: Maybe (even probably I'll acknowledge you may be right) - the short mission brief when HAL is being shutdown only mentions the Lunar one - but it begs the question of what the crew was planning to do out there.  Inspect every moon of Jupiter for anomalies?  In a later book when Jupiter ignites Europa gets a monolith to uplift the squid aliens. So it was a possibility they were expecting to find another one.

Comment: *"In a later book when Jupiter ignites Europa gets a monolith to uplift the squid aliens"* .. one of those great sentences one only sees in sci-fi discussions!!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the novel, it is clear that the transmission is picked up by a series of probes, which allowed the direction and destination to be picked up.

> And now Deep Space Monitor 79 had noted something strange - a faint
> yet unmistakable disturbance rippling across the Solar System, and
> quite unlike any natural phenomenon it had ever observed in the past.
> Automatically, it recorded the direction, the time, the intensity; in
> a few hours it would pass the information to Earth. As, also, would
> Orbiter M 15, circling Mars twice a day; and High Inclination Probe
> 21, climbing slowly above the plane of the ecliptic; and even
> Artificial Comet 5, heading out into the cold wastes beyond Pluto,
> along an orbit whose far point it would not reach for a thousand
> years.

> ‘After all these ages, one would naturally assume that it was inert.
> But soon after lunar sunrise, it emitted an extremely powerful blast
> of radio energy. We believe that this energy was merely the by-product - the backwash, as it were - of some unknown form of radiation, for at the same time, several of our space-probes detected an unusual
> disturbance crossing the Solar System. We were able to track it with
> great accuracy. It was aimed precisely at Saturn.

Comment: This definitely wasn't covered in the movie, which I just re-watched after many years.  I'm not even sure that I read the book.

Comment: Very long time since I watched the movie so couldn't comment on that source. Book was helpfully a lot more explicit (not entirely surprising from Clarke).

Comment: I would add a note that the movie replaced Saturn with Jupiter as the destination.

Comment: @Rad80 The movie was released before the novel.

Comment: @Acccumulation Both the book and the movie were developed contemporaneously.  The difference in destination from Saturn to Jupiter is discussed in [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177/67168)  question, and it comes down to the film people not having suitable images of Saturn's rings.

Comment: @Michael So, did Clarke predict Mars orbiters being a "common thing", or did the scientific community take Clarke's advice to heart? :) Now that's a chicken-and-egg question!